# Simple Oracle query started running slow when returning more than 251 results

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

As the title implies, I have a very simple Oracle query that is returning in 5 seconds when I go beyond returning 251 results. I am using SQL Developer, and attaching using the built in connection utility (there is no facility for an ODBC connection in this application).

The query found here is fast (fast enough) (pa_stu holds roughly 40k rows):

```
Select * From pa_stu Where rownum < 252;
```

Oracle returns the data to me in .521 second, according to SQL Developer.

The following query, and ones that pull larger sets of data, are the culprit:

```
Select * From pa_stu Where rownum < 253;
```

Oracle returns the data to me for that last one in 5.327 second, according to SQL Developer.

All queries being used for testing have the same explain plan. That is, the filter predicate of ROWNUM<251 (change the 251 to whatever number is being used) and a TABLE ACCESS of FULL.

The results above are consistent, plus, bumping up the evaluated number to about 1000 doubles the result time to roughly 10 seconds (consistently). It is as if some buffering is going on somewhere, and that buffer is too small. Additionally, this is happening on only one of our Oracle servers. The other, more highly used one (holds different data as well) has no problem returning 100's of thousands of records using similar statements.

The databases are controlled by a DBA, and, I have run all of this by her. She does not have a solution. This actually started happening a month or so back, and was not the case many months ago, if that is meaningful. It was just not as noticeable as it is now.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What are the wait events for the query?  Is it possible that the table is physically compact in one database (where the full table scan returns quickly) and that there are large expanses of allocated space that contains no data in another database (where the full table scan returns slowly)?

Comment: Do both queries have the same `EXPLAIN` information?

Comment: Um, how may rows in this table?  "bumping up the evaluated number to about 1000" - You don't mean to imply it's only 1,000?  Something is very broken unless you've got multiple millions of rows and/or no index on rownum.

Comment: PM 77-1 : Both queries have the same explain plan. That is, the filter predicate of ROWNUM<251 (change the 251 to whatever number is being used) and a TABLE ACCESS of FULL.

Comment: ebyrob : The table PA_STU (from the poor performing query) has roughly 40000 total rows in it. The table I tested from the other Oracle instance has roughly 400k rows in it right now. So it has 10 times the amount, but, runs as one would expect.

Comment: Justin : I have the DBA looking into your questions. I, unfortunately, don't have many rights to the database servers.

Also, I updated my original post with the other information requested.

Comment: Did you DBA find any empty blocks in the middle which causes the slowdown? Was there a huge delete on this table? Did you try to reorganize the table? Did you check the plan?

Comment: The news isn't any good concerning the followup from our DBA. She blamed the issue on Oracle running on the Windows machine and moved the instance to a virtual Linux machine running on one of the mainframes. Strangely enough, the issue did go away. Unfortunately, this coincidence only bolsters her desire to not use Windows machines, and more so, never getting to the real issue. I apologize, I did not have the power to take matters into my own hands this time. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You need to trace 10046 this to get the answer, please do so and upload results, also where are you pulling plans from? explain plan doesnt reeturn the used plan sometimes please go thorugh this article: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_do_i_know_if